# Web editor question

Tags: web

1. anybody can recommend a good web editor to me?
2. page created in windows should be working ok in linux as long as firefox support it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Here you have a list with 10 free web editors for windows:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/windowshtmleditors/tp/free-windows-editors.htm

(the first one komodo it's pretty good at least the mac version I use)
[Link](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/)

2.) OS and browser doesn't matter with HTML as long as you write (W3C compliant code).

In case of CSS & JavaScript some functions have different behaviors depending on the browser.

Comment: 2. isn't strictly true - many browsers don't conform to the W3C specs.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)
2. Firefox isn't the only browser used on Linux (I'm currently using Chrome). Fonts are something to look out for on Linux, so it's always worth testing.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com) editor. It is not cheap, but it is very good. My users like it.

I am assuming you mean a content editor for use on your site.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/) in the past. I also like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an editor with Syntax Highlighting then TextPad, KomodoEdit, NotePad++ are good.

Aptana Studio is also free and also provides Intellisense for HTML and Javascript editing.

If your page is W3C compliant, then it should be rendered well in any standard browser. Don't forget your DOCTYPE declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The most suitable web editor depends on what technologies you are using.
If you are using ASP .NET, then you should use [Visual Studio](https://web.archive.org/web/20150415113024/https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/vstudio/default.aspx).
For Java (JSP), Eclipse is what you want.
If you are asking about a more general web editor (html/javascript) and you are more likely to be using php or Ruby, you really need to give a try to : [PSPad](https://www.pspad.com/fr/). I have been using it for months, and it has a lot of cool features: from basic code editing to code verification etc. And yes, it's free! You can even add to it a lot of extensions.

For interoperability between navigators, you have to test your website on many of them as you can, be careful with Internet Explorer especially, [here you can find some known CSS bugs](https://css-tricks.com/ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/) that you may encoutner while running your pages on IE.

Alors I recommand you to use special tools that can do cross-navigator testing for you, like [Browsershots](https://browsershots.org/).